# How can I get the fonts family and font styles in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, java-9

I can't seem to get just the font family without getting a bunch of font styles. Here is my code I am thinking of separating them using a .contains to check for light, bold, italic but that isn't very efficient.

```
for(String font : Font.getFontNames()){
            if(font.toLowerCase().contains("light") || font.contains("extrabold") || font.contains("extralight") || font.contains("light")){

            }

        fontsList.add(font);
        }
```

My display is this :
Times New Roman

**Times New Roman Bold**

***Times New Roman Bold Italic***

*Times New Roman Italic*

But I only want to display the Time New Roman so only the font family.

Comment: Not able to understand, what your shared piece of code is actually trying to do. Esp with that empty `if` within the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `javafx.scene.text.Font` class offers [`Font#getFamilies`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/text/Font.html#getFamilies()) which, as you may guess, returns all of font families listed on the user's system.

Calling the following snippet produces the following output below it:

```
Font.getFamilies().forEach(System.out::println);
```

> ...
>
> Times New Roman
>
> ...

**Note**: Fonts such as `Copperplate Gothic Bold` still exist, as that's considered to be a font family.